# Do Magicians learn to read all languages they learn to speak, or just those they speak at level 1?

Tags: languages, shadow-of-the-demon-lord

The **Languages and Professions** line for Level 1 Magician says:

> You read all the languages you know how to speak.

Does this mean that the character learns how to read all languages they speak when they pick this path at level 1, but not any they learn afterwards; or does it mean that Magicians always know how to read any languages they learn - even languages they learn after picking this novice path? I can see reasons for it to work either way, but I've not been able to find an official ruling.

(As you may have guessed, I'm asking because my level 0 character only speaks one language - the Common Tongue - and I spent a profession pick during character creation to know how to read it already.)

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that “all” doesn't encompass every language? Are there rules for learning languages later?

Comment: Languages are granted at various levels, or can be taken instead of a profession when you get to choose a new one. Generally you just get whatever new Professions or Languages a level grants you, and those choices don't otherwise have an ongoing effect By default you can only speak the languages you learn but you can also forgo a profession or language pick to learn to read a language you already know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You know how to read all of them

A character in *Shadow of the Demon Lord* first has to learn how to **speak** a language, then they have to learn how to **write** in a language they already know how to speak. Both can be done by trading out a profession you would learn in order to gain the ability to speak or write in that language.

> **Languages and Professions**
>
> Your ancestry tells you the languages you can speak as well as any you know how to read and write.
>
> **Languages**
>
> You can trade out a profession to learn to speak another language or gain the ability to read a language you already know how to speak.

**Magicians** on the other hand have the ability to automatically know how to read all languages they learn how to speak. This means you can trade out a single profession to learn how to speak and write a specific language.

> **Languages and Professions**
>
> You read all the languages you know how to speak. In addition, you add one academic area of knowledge of your choice.